# NiFI's Cluster Management Menu is not found when using docker-compose

Tags: apache-nifi

Following this document there is a cluster menu to choose, 
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.2/bk_administration/content/clustering.html

but when using docker-compose https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/docker-compose/README.md

the cluster management menu is not found. I access the UI via
http://0.0.0.0:32768/nifi/. the port is found by using `docker-compose port nifi 8080`

My goal is to check the cluster behavior by making a container stop and start (not to kill), and check the data loss and the processor behaves

Answer (score 0):

so here mentions

> All released images 1.7.0 or later should work with the file as
>   provided

is not true. 
https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-docker/docker-compose/README.md#nifi-version-configuration

because the following environment variable which enables the cluster setup

`NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE` exists only after 1.8.0

so apprently 1.7.1 doesn't work